# cannot insert to enum type in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, enums

i have 2 enum value type in mysql i want insert to that here my code

```
                   newOrderSingleEntity newordersingleObj = new newOrderSingleEntity();
                 newordersingleObj.setSymbol(message.getString(Symbol.FIELD));
                        System.out.print(" symbol "+message.getString(Symbol.FIELD));
                        newordersingleObj.setTransactTime(message.getString(TransactTime.FIELD)); 
                     newordersingleObj.setOrdType(enumOrderType.PEGGED);
                     System.out.print(" time " +message.getString(TransactTime.FIELD));
                        newordersingleObj.setClOrdID(message.getString(ClOrdID.FIELD));
                        System.out.print(" ClOrdID "+message.getString(ClOrdID.FIELD));
                        newordersingleObj.setOrderID(message.getString(OrderID.FIELD));
                        System.out.print(" OrderID "+message.getString(OrderID.FIELD));
                        newordersingleObj.setExecID(message.getString(ExecID.FIELD));
                        System.out.print(" ExecID "+message.getString(ExecID.FIELD));
                        newordersingleObj.setExecTransType(exectype);
                        System.out.print(" ExecTransType "+message.getString(ExecTransType.FIELD));
                        System.out.print(" OrdType "+message.getString(OrdType.FIELD));
                        newordersingleObj.setExecType(message.getString(ExecType.FIELD));
                        System.out.print(" ExecType "+message.getString(ExecType.FIELD));
                         newordersingleObj.setOrderStatus(enumOrderStatus.NEW);
                        RepositoryFactory.getOrderRepository().create(newordersingleObj);
```

and here my enum class

```
public enum enumOrderStatus {
    NEW, PARTIALFILLED, FILLED, DONEFORDAY, CANCELLED, REJECTED, EXPIRED
}
public enum enumOrderType {
    PEGGED, LIMIT, MARKETORDER
}
```

and here my entity

```
 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        @Column(name="OrderStatus")
        private enumOrderStatus OrderStatus;

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        @Column(name="OrdType")
        private enumOrderType OrdType;
public String getOrderStatus() {
            return this.OrderStatus.name();
        }

        public void setOrderStatus(enumOrderStatus OrderStatus) {
            this.OrderStatus = OrderStatus;
        }

        public String getOrdType() {
            return this.OrdType.name();
        }

        public void setOrdType(enumOrderType OrdType) {
            this.OrdType = OrdType;
        }
```

the problem is apps cannot insert to mysql when there is any enum type here.... so how to fix my problem i have follow step by step in internet

Comment: Could you please share your exception with a stacktrace?

Comment: JPA does not support database enum types. You must use a converter https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/

Comment: Or don't bother with enum. Instead store allowable values in a separate table (or tables).

Comment: this close after use converter... and after check the limit of record in mysql thanks all